# FUNCTION "SUM does not exist"

Tags: mysql, .net

I am using mysql 5.5.11, when i execute the script below

```
INSERT INTO payments(created,  Amount,  user,  Remarks,  orderid,  paymethod) 
VALUES('2016-09-03', 0.0, 'admin', '', 4, 'Cash');
```

I get error

> SQL Error: FUNCTION mydb.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name
>   Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

This is the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE payments (
  ID         int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  OrderID    int,
  Amount     decimal(11,2),
  Created    varchar(20),
  Remarks    varchar(160),
  user       varchar(60),
  PayMethod  varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  /* Keys */
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

What could be the cause of the error

This is the trigger attached to the table

```
BEGIN
  /* Trigger text */
  UPDATE Orders Set Paid =(Select SUM (Amount) From Payments AS p Where p.OrderID  = Orders.ID),PayMethod =new.PayMethod  WHere Orders.id = new.OrderID;
   UPDATE Orders Set Bal = Total - Paid  WHere Orders.id = new.OrderID;
END
```

Comment: Is there any trigger on that table?

Comment: In addition to what @Hamlet asked... `user` is a reserved word in most DBMSs. If you're going to have a column with that name, you have to properly escape it each and every time you use it. If it were me, I'd find a different name for that column to avoid the headaches and extra work it is going to cause you.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, yes I attached the trigger

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Look at trigger:

```
UPDATE Orders Set Paid =(Select SUM (Amount) From Payments AS p Where p.OrderID  = Orders.ID),PayMethod =new.PayMethod  WHere Orders.id = new.OrderID;
```

MySQL does not accept spaces between function name and parenthesis (unless you have set SQL_MODE=IGNORE_SPACE but that gives you other undesirable side effects)

You can check the SQL_MODE setting by running:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'SQL_MODE';
```

MySQL documentation about this: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/function-resolution.html)

Some example:

```
mysql> select sum(5);
+--------+
| sum(5) |
+--------+
|      5 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sum (5);
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION sum does not exist
```

Solution: Remove space

```
UPDATE Orders Set Paid =(Select SUM(Amount) From Payments AS p Where p.OrderID  = Orders.ID),PayMethod =new.PayMethod  WHere Orders.id = new.OrderID;
```

Comment: How to tell sqlyog to ignore space as its everytime adding space after sum and count when we click on format sql query

Comment: That is the most misleading error message I have ever seen.

Answer (score 14):

Remove spaces between `SUM` and `(` like this: `Select SUM(Amount) From Payments`.

Comment: For me it was a missing space between the end ")" and the "," - syntax is pretty strict with the mysql command line client

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between "SUM" and "(".
[The space show in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbjQH.png)

[Refer the link further studies](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space)