# Do math functions require routine privileg on MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql

I migrated from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 and the same application now throws this error:

```
 msg="query error" logger=tsdb.mysql err="Error 1370: execute command denied to user 'myuser'@'localhost' for routine 'mydatabase.SUM'"
```

The user is granted the select privileg like on 5.7

Do Math functions require more privileges?

I changed SQL mode before, because I needed full group by. Might this be the cause?

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Answer (score 0):

have you followed the upgrade instructions this shouldn't happen

But do a

```
 1. log in as `root`
 2. `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION `db_name`.`mydatabase` TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
 3. `flush privileges;`
```

And then all should run again

Comment: There is no routine with the Name "SUM". Executing the grant command results in an error.  The function causing it, is a simple SQL query with SUM in it.
Might this be because of switching sQL mode?

Comment: Found it! Spaces are not supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309859/function-sum-does-not-exist removed the space in SELECT SUM (5) to SUM(5)

Comment: True, sorry about that. Did not think about the query as it was working before. On the other server the sql mode contains: IGNORE_SPACE